# not able to display tabhost inside fragment android

Tags: android, fragment, android-tabhost

i am creating a TabHost inside fragment. i am having 2 fragments in my fragmentActivity and i want the tabhost in my right fragment. but TabHost is not displaying and the activity is forced closed giving nullpointerexception

this is the code in my fragment where i am calling TabHost

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View  view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menucat, container, false);
     mTabHost=(TabHost)getView().findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);


     TabHost.TabSpec spec;  
     mTabHost.setup();

         intent=new Intent(getActivity(),Activity1.class);



        spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("soups").setIndicator("Soups").setContent(intent);

        mTabHost.addTab(spec);



        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);        

     return view;
        }
```

this is my layout which i am using to create tabhost.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

you use wrong way to access tabhost where tabhohst id is autogenerated but you can manually pass it.

```
TabHost tab=getTabhost();
```

Donot pass tab id.

```
 <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
```

Comment: your tabhost id is auto generated  android:id="@android:id/tabhost"

Comment: Try this     TabHost tab=getTabhost();

Comment: Are you extend tabhost instead of activity.I think you cannot extend tabhost in .java class.

Comment: no I am extending fragment as I want the tabhost to be displayed inside fragment